# php to parse ascii text from file get contents

Tags: php, parsing, curl, file-get-contents

Good morning all, i have a new question:
I'm trying to save into mysql a set of data coming from a SIMBAD database query (it's a stellar objects dataabse).
If you enter this url into the browser: http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?output.format=ASCII&Ident=hd%201&OutputMode=VOTable
you get a result formated with separate lines, but if you use

```
<?php
$cadaart = 'http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?output.format=ASCII&Ident=hd%201';
$handler = curl_init($cadaart);
$response = curl_exec ($handler);
curl_close($handler);
echo $response;
?>
```

or a simple file_get_content and echo the response you get a single line with all information, which makes me impossible to parse... Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the information is on one line? If you're viewing the result in your browser, try to view the source or surround the output with `"<pre>" . $response . "</pre>"`.

Comment: Same thing cweiske, using your line displays same result. If i view source code i see it same as on the webpage, my idea is that there is kind of a new line, but can't find it using nl2br or str_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is already with line-break,
you can use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to convert contents from that URL into an array (each line is an array element)

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just the difference between an LF and a CRLF. The output from your URL is LF, which, in where you're viewing it (browser?), is probably not parsed as a new line.
Try `$response = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $response);` and see if this makes any difference